# JamonAdmin in Different Servlet Container

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jamon

I have a web application running on Weblogic. It has  com.jamonapi:jamon:2.81 as maven dependency.
I'm using `org.springframework.aop.interceptor.JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor` with aop configuration. For every service/dao method call, jamon interceptor calculates statistics and stores them in memory.

I setup a jetty base for deploying jamon.war and started it. I can access it via http://localhost:3162/jamon/jamonadmin.jsp

However, it shows only local statistics. It doesn't show any statistics from my web application running on Weblogic. This did not suprise me since I didn't do any configuration for this. The question is that how can I do this magic configuration to make jamon.war see the statistics collected in my web application running on weblogic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define jamon as a provided scope dependency in your webapp's pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jamonapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jamon</artifactId>
    <version>2.81</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will ensure that your Weblogic webapp uses the jamonapi.jar files in your servlet container (jetty/lib/jamon-2.81.jar) instead of a duplicate copy deployed with the webapp itself.